# Rank of an adjugate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a matrix $2000\times2000$ and $Y=\operatorname{adj}(X)$. What are the possibilities the rank of $Y$ to be?
I can't seem to understand how that size of the matrix is helping in solving the problem. Any hints?

Edit: I forget to tell that $X$ is singular matrix.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the rank of $X$ in this answer, or are you only supposed to give an answer based on $2000$? At any rate, note that $XY$ can only have two possible ranks, and the rank of a product is limited both above and below by the ranks of the factor matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $XY = \det(X)I$.  When $\det(X) \neq 0$, we deduce that $Y$ has full rank.  When $\operatorname{rank}(X) \leq 2000-2$, the [equivalence of determinantal rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Determinantal_rank_%E2%80%93_size_of_largest_non-vanishing_minor) to the usual rank tells us that $Y = 0$.  All that's left is for you to deduce the rank of $Y$ in the case of $\operatorname{rank}(X) = 2000 - 1$, in which case we have $XY = 0$ but $Y \neq 0$.  To that end, see the hint given to you in Arthur's comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forget to tell that $X$ is a singular matrix. How does it changes your answer?

Comment: That just eliminates the case with $\det(X)\neq0$